# Object level implication in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle, implication

I see that many theorems in Isabelle/HOL prefer meta-level implication:

```
==>
```

instead of

```
-->
```

the object logic level, i.e. higher order logic implication.

[Isabelle wiki](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/community/FAQ#There_are_lots_of_arrows_in_Isabelle.2FHOL._What.27s_the_difference_between_-.3E.2C_.3D.3E.2C_--.3E.2C_and_.3D.3D.3E_.3F) says that *roughly speaking, meta level implication should be used to separate the assumptions from the conclusion in rule statements*.

Other than that, what should I know about the use of object and meta level implication? I see the latter is being used mostly. When and for what should I use HOL implication?

Comment: You might be able to infer useful information with regard to your query from the following (and, perhaps, some other related) posts on the mailing list: https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2018-December/msg00031.html and  https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2019-January/msg00019.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the short answer is: Use `==>` whenever possible as it is easier to work with than `-->`.

That being said, you should not see `==>` too often in the code you write.

1. When writing a Lemma, it is often nicer to use the `assumes` and `shows` syntax.
2. For intermediate steps with `have` there is a syntax with `if`:
   `have "B" if "A"` instead of `have "B ==> A"`
3. The meta implication can only be used at the top level, so if you have a predicate as argument to a function you cannot use `==>` in that predicate.